# How to delete second occurrence from a line using Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, find

I have below data in file

```
They used to carry lots of treats
but now they don’t have any sweets.
And so, if you’re in need of candy,
please don’t visit Mrs. Mandy. He is working in office.But will be late from office
```

**For example :**

using this following command i got the line which as both keywords in same line

```
grep "Mandy" file.txt | grep "office"
```

The above command as given me below line as output

```
please don’t visit Mrs. Mandy. He is working in office.But will be late from office
```

Now from above line which i got as an output need to delete second occurrence keyword : `office` and print below output

**Expected output :**

```
please don’t visit Mrs. Mandy. He is working in office.But will be late from
```

How to achieve the above expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` can do that using `s/office//2`. On top of that, you can combine the entire pipeline into a single command.

```
sed -n '/Mandy/s/office//2p' file.txt
```

Explanation:

In above command there are 2 `sed` commands.

1. `/Mandy/` runs the next command only on lines containing `Mandy`.
2. `s/office//2p` deletes  (**s**ubstitute with the empty string) the **2**nd occurrence of `office` in those lines and **p**rints them afterwards.

Comment: can you elaborate your solution this point  `/Mandy/s/office//2p` and why `s` is given

Comment: @codeholic24 I updated the answer. `s` is a sed command.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
grep "Mandy" file.txt | grep "office" | grep -oP '.*(?=office)(?=office)'
```

This uses regex with positive lookahead.
It produces the output you are looking for:

```
please don’t visit Mrs. Mandy. He is working in office.But will be late from
```

Comment: `.*(?=office)(?=office)` is equivalent to `.*(?=office)` and does *not* remove the second `office`, but simply the last one and everything after that.